# Not able to use a VM instance in GCP as webhook

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

I am trying to use as webhook a VM instance in GCP. (restfull service using nginx)
The code work properly in local, I am able to raise a test server using ngrok an it works properly.
When I try to point in dialogflow to the VM instance, if I use external IP in the path I get a webhook error with code 14

```
  "webhookStatus": {
    "code": 14,
    "message": "Webhook call failed. Error: UNAVAILABLE."
```

If I used internal IP in the path, I get error code 2

```
  "webhookStatus": {
    "code": 2,
    "message": "Webhook call failed. Error: UNKNOWN."
```

Any of these calls are registered in nginx logs.

However, if I launch the path in a browser (using external IP, of course) or from postman, I get a proper answer

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance, and sorry if I am missing some stupid detail :(
Cheers

Comment: Did you have check the firewall rules?

Comment: As  @guillaumeblaquiere mentioned, have you checked that? Alson,  have you followed the [Webhook service requirements](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/fulfillment-webhook#requirements) and [Authentication](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/fulfillment-webhook#auth)?